# Surface MeshFunction with independently spaced parameters

Tags: plotting

```
surfuv = {Sech[u] Cos[v],( u-Tanh[v]), Sech[u] Sin[v]};
g1 =
  ParametricPlot3D[surfuv, {u,-Pi,Pi}, {v,- Pi, Pi},
    BoxRatios->Automatic, PlotPoints->25, MeshFunctions->{#1&},
    MeshStyle->Purple, MeshShading->{None,Green,None,Yellow}];
g2 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[surfuv,{u,-Pi,Pi},{v,- Pi,Pi},
    BoxRatios->Automatic, PlotPoints->25, MeshFunctions->{#2&},
    MeshStyle->Purple, MeshShading->{None,Green,None,Yellow}];
Show[{g1, g2}, PlotRange->All]
```

Is it possible to show the surface sliced or partitioned not at uniform intervals  of (x, y, z) but  from (u, v) directly? I believe it would be quite useful in visualization of 2D surfaces (embedded in 3 space) during their generation/first-definition.

I can increment `u, v` in uniform steps without blanking out alternate slices. Does shading `None` also help likewise?

Comment: Try using `#4 &` and `#5 &` as the `MeshFunction`s. (This is all in the docs for `ParametricPlot3D[]`.)

Comment: Thank you, guess it works like magic !